# Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04

Can someone guide me to a nice artice where I can like the list of things to consider if you want to strip all the unwanted processes/services in the server while its sole purpose is used as a web-server using Java, Tomcat and Mysql.

when I do a

```
ps aux | wc -l
```

I get 112. Want to make sure none of them are unwanted service and can be safely stopped (or not started while the server comes up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. What kind of unwanted processes is it you think are intentionally added to Ubuntu Server? It is designed to be a very basic system because it's intended for servers. So it doesn't run any services other than the ones you install.

There are of course a large number of great books you can read about Linux system administration, but you probably won't find many articles about "things to remove after installing Ubuntu Server".

The first hundred processes or so are related to the kernel and are critical. They enable your hardware or very low level system things that the kernel needs. These are in brackets [] and if you do a `ps ax`, you'll see that they represent almost all of your processes. There will be a few others, such as the init system (process 1), your login shell and things like that.

Comment: Thank you @Jo. Looking that big number 112 processes, I was little bit concerned since the machine I'm using is not very powerful. Now my mind is at ease. If you can refer some books about Linux administration, that'll be great, nevertheless I will accept the answer.